# Kworker linux process: what is it writing to disk?

Tags: linux, installation, debian

I'm on *Debian Jessie 8.2*. Is there a way to figure out what exactly is being written out by **kworker** or what's triggering those writes?
I'm using a flash drive for my OS.

```
deathstar> dmesg|grep sdc|grep WRITE
[  335.765626] hwclock(991): WRITE block 8900608 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020065] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 21037080 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020094] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 8 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020099] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 4194576 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020103] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 4194672 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020107] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 8388616 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020112] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 8389088 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020116] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 20971520 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020121] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 20971648 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020125] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 20971832 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020129] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 20971848 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  361.020133] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 20972000 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  366.028174] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 4581024 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
[  386.060077] kworker/u4:3(95): WRITE block 4644368 on sdc1 (8 sectors)
```

[EDIT]

```
The disk isn't full
/dev/sdc1 15G 5.5G 8.1G 41% / 

cat write|grep WRITE|wc 
69 lines but accumulates over 1hr
```

I tried the **perf record -g -a** suggested below:
I'm seeing things like:

```
 -    0.02%     0.02%     kworker/u4:4  [kernel.kallsyms]                 [k] i915_gem_object_move_to_inactive
 -    0.02%     0.02%     kworker/u4:4  [kernel.kallsyms]                 [k] cpuacct_charge
 +    0.03%     0.03%     kworker/u4:4  [kernel.kallsyms]                 [k] radix_tree_next_chunk
 +    0.03%     0.03%     kworker/u4:4  [kernel.kallsyms]                 [k] strlen
 +    0.03%     0.03%     kworker/u4:4  [kernel.kallsyms]                 [k] radix_tree_lookup_slot
 +    0.03%     0.03%     kworker/u4:4  [kernel.kallsyms]                 [k] find_get_pages
 +    0.03%     0.03%     kworker/u4:4  [kernel.kallsyms]                 [k] inc_zone_page_state
 +    0.04%     0.04%     kworker/u4:4  [kernel.kallsyms]                 [k] check_addr
```

i think perhaps it's the i915 driver but what now?

Comment: How do i do something like perf -e ext4:ext4_write_begin and match on sdc and print the filename/process? eg: dtrace -n probe /filter/ { action; }

Comment: I need to do something like: dtrace -n 'io:::start /execname == "kworker"/ { printf("%d %s %s", pid, execname, fileinfo_t}'